# Can Message::GetDescriptor() return null?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm always checking the return value of `Message::GetDescriptor()` before using it, but when would it ever return null? Is it perhaps unnecessary to check the return value?

The docs:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Message.GetDescriptor.details

Declaration:

```
const Descriptor * 
    Message::GetDescriptor() const
```

Answer (score 1):

You should **always** check return type of **possibly every API** that you code invokes, and should never make any kind of **assumption** however reliable the API may be. API s fail for a variety of reasons beyond human control:-

- Network condition fluctuations including PHY disruption  (not applicable in this case)
- System running the implementation of the API running **Out of Resource** like space
- System overload (too busy with other processes)
- Unreliable API implementation (bug) 
  etc..

Since the API is from **Google** making a naive assumption that the 4th reason can never be true simply reduces the **robustness** of your software. For 99.99% of times it might just seem to be a *redundant* check or an over protective code - but for that 0.01% times when it fails you have unreliable behavior from your software

The costliest bugs that could have easily been avoided (if not fixed), from my experience over the years, are a result overlooking simple and basic error handling

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to check it, for each message you should get a non NULL pointer.